# FastReport4 fieldname in delphixe4

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I'm using FastReport4 in DelphiXE4.
I set Connection String at RunTime Like this:

```
ADOConnection.ConnectionString := ConStr;
ADOConnection.Connected := True;
AdoQuery1.Connection := ADOConnection;
```

So I cannot see preview in FastReport Designer!
I have a query like this:

```
AdoQuery.Sql.Text :='SELECT Table1.title,Table2.title FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON (Table1.code=Table2.id);';
```

I have a problem with Field name in FastReport Designer.
I tested [frxDBDataset1."Table1.title"], but Field Not Found !
Then I changed Query Like This:

```
AdoQuery.Sql.Text :='SELECT Table1.title as f1,Table2.title as f2 FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON (Table1.code=Table2.id);';
```

and in FastReport Designer:

`[frxDBDataset1."f1"]`

But same error occurred!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Select `frxDBDataset` and clear all `FieldAliasis` then use this:

```
AdoQuery.Sql.Text :='SELECT Table1.title as f1,Table2.title as f2 FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON (Table1.code=Table2.id);';
```

And:

```
[frxDBDataset1."f1"]
```